# Making white backgrounds transparent in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, pixel

Currently using JavaScript and canvas to get rid of white background of image and make it transparent.
The method below should do this but `g.putImageData(imgd,0,0);` (Last Line) gives me an error: `TypeError: g.putImageData is not a function.`

Why is this or is there an easier way to make all images on my canvas with white background transparent?

```
var imgd = g.getImageData(leftX,leftY,Weight,Height),
pix = imgd.data,
newColor = {r:0,g:0,b:0,a:0};

for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i<n; i +=4) {
    var r = pix[i],
    g = pix[i+1],
    b = pix[i+2];

    if (r == 225 && g == 225 && b == 225 ) {
        pix[i] = newColor.r;
        pix[i+1] = newColor.g;
        pix[i+2] = newColor.b;
        pix[i+3] = newColor.a;
    }
}
g.putImageData(imgd,0,0);
```

Comment: You are redefining `g` to the green value in your `for` loop so it doesn't point to the context anymore. Fix that and it should all work

Comment: Unless you're looking specifically for a `#e1e1e1` white, you should instead do `if (r >= 225 && g >= 225 && b >= 225 )`. Most images have noise, and the definition of white slightly changes.

Comment: @Rhumborl Thank you very much this worked, If I have many images on the canvas is there a way to make them all transparent at once?

Comment: @user3558118 You'd have to paint them all then select the image currently on the canvas to do it all at once, but it'd only affect the visible state of them all. Otherwise you could use an array and a loop to go through them all

Comment: @user3558118. Your current method will replace any & all the white pixels on the canvas--even white pixels inside an image.